# Is there a way to create a unique constraint for 2 tables?

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I have the following 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE google_subscription (
    fk_customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id_constraint
        FOREIGN KEY(fk_customer_id) 
        REFERENCES customer(id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE apple_subscription (
    fk_customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id_constraint
        FOREIGN KEY(fk_customer_id) 
        REFERENCES customer(id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

1. `google_subscription` is having `fk_customer_id` referencing to `customer` table `id`.
2. `apple_subscription` is having `fk_customer_id` referencing to `customer` table `id`.

I was wondering, is it ever possible to create a constraint, such that `customer` table `id`, will only be found in either `google_subscription` or `apple_subscription`, but NOT both?

Comment: Merge both google_subscription and apple_subscription tables into a single table. That solves your problem and gives you a better datamodel that also supports other subscriptions, like Amazon and Microsoft without changing the datamodel again.

Comment: The reason we prefer to have different tables, as Google & Apple are using different data (aka different columns required) to deal with subscription. As we support more billing providers, table schema requirement will also be differ. Hence, it is better to have different tables for each billing providers.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible. A constraint cannot span across multiple tables. Instead you can have another table `subscriptions` where you can have a unique index on `customer(id)`. Or you can have another column in customer table which will hold only 1 subscription at a time.